# Compare and store elements of multidimensional array to two new arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Assume I have the following simple array:

```
my_array = np.array([[1,2],[2,4],[3,6],[2,1]])
```

which corresponds to another parent array:

```
parent_array = np.array([0,1,2,3])
```

Of course, there is a function that maps `parent_array` to `np.array` but it is not important what function this is.

**Goal**:
I want to use this `my_array` so as to create two new arrays `A` and `B` by iterating each row of `my_array`: `for row i` if the value of the first column of `my_array[i]` is greater than the value of the second column I will store `parent_array[i]` in `A` . Otherwise I will store `parent_array[i]`  in `B` (if the value of the second column in `my_array[i]` if bigger).

So for the case above the result would be:

```
A = [3]
```

because only in the 4-th value of `my_array` the first column has greater value and

```
  B = [0,1,2]
```

because the in the first three rows the second column has greater value.

Now, **although I know how to save the greater element in a row of columns to a new array, the fact that each row in** `my_array` **is associated with a row in** `parent_array` **is confusing me. I don't know how to correlate them.**

---

***Summary***:
I need therefore to associate each row of `parent_array` to each row of `my_array` and then if check row by row the latter and if the value of the first column is greater in `my_array[i]` I save `parent_row[i]` in A while if the second column is greater in `my_array[i]` I save `parent_row[i]` in B.

Answer (score 0):

Use [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) for this: create boolean condition array by comparing values from 1st and 2nd column of `my_array` and then use it to select values from `parent_array`:

```
cond = my_array[:,0] > my_array[:,1]
A, B = parent_array[cond], parent_array[~cond]
A
# [3]
B
# [0 1 2]
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. Ok thanks, very quick and efficient solution. Thanks a lot.